# this module has outdated symbols

Tags: c, stack

The following is a C call stack dump running on a JDE EnterpriseOne server.

```
_IB4210900_ProcessUnprocessedLines@12! CSALES.dll  
_IB4210900_PerformSalesOrderAction@32! CSALES.dll  
_SalesOrderApplCtrlEX@12! CSALES.dll  
_jdeCallObjectV2@44! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_jdeCallObject@40! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_JDEK_ProcessCallRequest@24! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_JDEK_StartCallRequest@16! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_runBusinessFunction@4! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_runCallObjectJob@4! jdekrnl.dll  <-**this module has outdated symbols**
_psthread_pool_job_execute@4! PSThreadUtils.dll
```

I am wondering what this message "this module has outdated symbols" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the symbol definitions compiled for that dll (.pdb?) do not match the code for the dll. It could mean that the symbol definitions were not updated, or that Windows is finding the wrong version because some older definitions are in a location that take precedence.